# parseFloat bug in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, parsefloat

It seems a very simple question.
the result of parseFloat in IE is different from the results in Chrome and FF.
Here is the very simple code

```
<html>
    <script>
        var lat = parseFloat(" 25.482688176812758");
        alert(lat);
    </script>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

then try to open it in IE the alert is 25.482688176812757
but in chrome and FF is 25.482688176812758

Comment: did you try to remove the empty space ?

Comment: Which IE? This works fine on IE10 and IE11 (with the space).

Comment: it gets more crazy.. check out: Number("25.482688176812758").toPrecision(20)..

Comment: in my IE 10, parseFloat("25.482688176812758") gives me ending in..276

Comment: @Frederic I've tried no change by removing the space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the browser limitation of decimal places in implementation of Numbers.

A workaround is to use the library [BigDecimal](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js).

More on [Floating-point cheat sheet for JavaScript](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/javascript/).

Comment: While I'm not disagreeing with you -- I'm just curious.  If the browsers all using IEEE 754 floating point, shouldn't all of the browsers have the same behavior?

Comment: Should, but IE does not have the same behavior as others. It's tricky to work with this precision of data in JavaScript. i.e. Try to put in console Chrome/FF and IE this `25.482688176812758.toFixed(15) + '\n' + 25.482688176812758.toFixed(16);`. More, change 15 by 20 in both browsers..